# How to eliminate this Column not found error?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Originally, the entity `Gut` had a field `reaction` that contained a string. The options for `reaction` were hard-wired in a template. By adding an entity `Reaction` and changing the `Gut` form's `reaction` to an `EntityType` I'm now plagued with the error message

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.reaction' in 'field list'
```

even though I've rewritten the `Gut` & `Reaction` entities. I've probably lost sight of the forest for the trees. What's wrong with the following?

MySQL table `gut`: `reaction` column replaced by `reaction_id`; `reaction_id` correctly created; foreign key created manually.

Error occurs with this controller method:

```
    #[Route('/', name: 'app_gut_index', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function index(GutRepository $gutRepository): Response
    {
        $guts = $gutRepository->findBy([], ['happened' => 'DESC']); // error thrown here
        
        return $this->render('gut/index.html.twig', [
                    'guts' => $guts,
        ]);
    }
```

`Gut` entity:

```
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Reaction::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'reaction_id', referencedColumnName: 'id')]
    protected $reaction;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $description = null;

    #[ORM\Column(name: "datetime")]
    private ?\DateTime $happened = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getReaction(): ?Reaction
    {
        return $this->reaction;
    }

    public function setReaction(?Reaction $reaction): self
    {
        $this->reaction = $reaction;

        return $this;
    }
...
}
```

`Reaction` entity:

```
use App\Entity\Gut;
use App\Repository\ReactionRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ReactionRepository::class)]
class Reaction
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->guts = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 45)]
    private ?string $reaction = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getReaction(): ?string
    {
        return $this->reaction;
    }

    public function setReaction(string $reaction): self
    {
        $this->reaction = $reaction;

        return $this;
    }

    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: Gut::class, mappedBy: 'reaction')]
    private $guts;

    /**
     * @return Collection|Product[]
     */
    public function getGuts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->guts;
    }

    public function addGut($gut): self
    {
        $this->guts[] = $gut;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getReaction();
    }

}
```

Comment: So `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` shows everything is in sync?  Can you show the form code for `->add('reaction',...`?  And of course you have cleared the cache.

Comment: You database schema is not in sync with your entities. More specifically one of your entities have a field which is not actually in the database. Maybe you forgot to run and/or generate your migration?

Comment: Schema definitely not in sync. Update replaced `gut.reaction_id` with `...reaction`. After updating, `gut.reaction` column is empty, but restored from backup. Error now `getReaction(): Return value must be of type ?App\Entity\Reaction, string returned`. No `add()` is present.

Comment: What stumps me is that I would expect that ManyToOne would create a SQL statement with a JOIN in it. Like `select g.id, r.reaction, g.`description`, g.`datetime` from gut g join reaction r on r.id = g.reaction order by g.`datetime` asc`. Instead, the log shows `SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.reaction AS reaction_2, t0.description AS description_3, t0.datetime AS datetime_4 FROM gut t0 ORDER BY t0.datetime DESC`.

Comment: Just for kicks, create a new database and run doctrine:schema:create just to see what you get with a fresh start.  Might help to narrow down the issue.  You are correct, the database column name should be reaction_id.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. I'd actually tried your suggestion and ended up no real where. Since this is an in-house, family member project, I'm just going to go back to hard-wired reactions. Glad I've got a series of git commits to revert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just couldn't let go. I eventually found a path to get the Gut and Reaction entities to play nicely together. What I did:

- cloned the project
- manually deleted reaction property from Gut entity; created & executed a migration
- in MySQL, added back in a reaction column
- used `make:entity Gut` to add a reaction property as ManyToOne on Reaction; made a migration
- used MySQL to populate the reaction_id column from the database of the cloned project.
- (Probably missed a step in here somewhere, but) `gut->getReaction()`,etc,
  now behave as expected - in a ManyToOne relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$reaction` property should not have both `ORM\Column` and `ORM\JoinColumn` annotations at the same time.

Because of this Doctrine thinks it's a regular column so it's looking for a database field based on the variable name: `$reaction` -> `gut.reaction`.

Remove `#[ORM\Column(length: 255)]` then make sure that you have `gut.reaction_id` in your database and now it should work.

As a little side note I don't think you need `name: 'reaction_id', referencedColumnName: 'id'` in `ORM\JoinColumn` because that's how Doctrine will name them automatically anyway